# Apache Flink: What does "Class X does not contain a setter for field Y" mean?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm playing around with flink (1.6, 1.7) for the first time and using the data from the github archive at https://www.gharchive.org/ but using that data as a streaming datasource.

My simple example just counts up all the events per user for a daily window and I'm trying to replicate the same example but using TableEnvironment and SQL Support instead.

However, I am encountering the following error:

**class org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.TimestampedFileInputSplit does not contain a setter for field modificationTime** as per below:

```
 8-12-04 14:17:02:115  INFO main exploration.StreamingTableApp:32 - Starting Streaming Table Flink App Example...
18-12-04 14:17:02:174  INFO main typeutils.TypeExtractor:1818 - class org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.TimestampedFileInputSplit does not contain a setter for field modificationTime
18-12-04 14:17:02:176  INFO main typeutils.TypeExtractor:1857 - Class class org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.TimestampedFileInputSplit cannot be used as a POJO type because not all fields are valid POJO fields, and must be processed as GenericType. Please read the Flink documentation on "Data Types & Serialization" for details of the effect on performance.
18-12-04 14:17:02:937  INFO main exploration.StreamingTableApp:74 - Finished...
```

I'm reading the CSV source as a datastream and using Gson to parse out bits of the json line and mapping these attributes to a Tuple.

Does anyone have any ideas / experience with this ?

**main method**:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);

// Mapped in docker compose file too.
DataStreamSource<String> input = env.readTextFile("/some/path/github/");

// Setup the stream
DataStream<Tuple4<String, Integer, String, Long>> stream = input.map(new GithubTupleConverter())
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new TupleTimestampExtractor());

StreamTableEnvironment tEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env);
Table tableFromStream = tEnv.fromDataStream(stream, "user_id, kount, basic_date,event_date");
```

**TupleTimestampExtractor**

```
public class TupleTimestampExtractor
        extends BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<Tuple4<String, Integer, String, Long>> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3737675541965835242L;

    public TupleTimestampExtractor() {
        super(Time.seconds(30L));
    }

    @Override
    public long extractTimestamp(Tuple4<String, Integer, String, Long> element) {
        return element.getField(3);
    }
}
```

**GithubTupleConverter.java**

```
public class GithubTupleConverter implements MapFunction<String, Tuple4<String, Integer, String, Long>> {

    private static final Gson g = new Gson();

    @Override
    public Tuple4<String, Integer, String, Long> map(String value) throws Exception {
        // Take each line as Json.
        JsonObject o = g.fromJson(value, JsonObject.class);

        // Extract the user id
        String userId = o.get("actor").getAsJsonObject().get("login").getAsString();

        // Extract the event type (commit, pull request, fork event)
        String type = o.get("type").getAsString();

        // Get the event date time
        String dateTime = o.get("created_at").getAsString();

        // Parse date string to Typed type.
        LocalDateTime eventTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);

        // Format the date so it can be used in the output.
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE;

        return Tuple4.of(userId, 1, formatter.format(eventTime), eventTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logs that you share do not show an error. The logs are on `INFO` level and no exception is thrown (at least not in the provided logs).

The log entry just says that the class `TimestampedFileInputSplit` cannot be treated as a POJO. In general this message indicates that the performance is not optimal but in this particular case it is not a problem.

Do you get any other error message?

Comment: Ok, this is my bad. It read like an error. But doesn't actually throw any exceptions. Thanks @Fabian.

Comment: I receive excessive such log. and it blows my hard disk. Is there a way to mute it?

Comment: It is true the log message is under INFO. But the message it self (as I understand it ..) makes me feel that something is really wrong and I cant understand the actual impact from the message.